# How do I build on occupied Land in Mafia City (mobile)?

Tags: mafia-city

I am currently at Boss Level 10 and my Mansion is at Level 8. Right now I've built buildings in almost all the slots inside my Turf. I wanted more space therefore I sent an Ops Team to occupy a small land slot that is located nearby but *outside my Turf*. However after occupying that land, it does not show me any option like *'Start Building'*.

Is there a way that an occupied land slot can be used to build a building?

Comment: @Robotnik Thanks for adding the tag!